# How can I make use of `::selection` for <input> in chrome browsers?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, selection, browser-support

I am trying to set a background and color for Input values. I succeeded doing that `::-moz-selection` for Mozilla  browsers, but `::selection` in Chrome and other browsers like Opera doesn't work.

Screenshot of the form in  Chrome- `::selection`. It **fails**:

[image: Doesn't work in Chrome]

Screenshot of the form in Mozilla Firefox- `::-moz-selection`. It **works**:

[image: Works fine in Mozilla Firefox]

Here is my code:

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="John"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Doe"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Your first and last name, please!!!.</p>
```

And the CSS:

```
::selection
{
color: #fff;
background: green;
}
::-moz-selection
{
color: #fff;
background: green;
}
input::selection
{
color: #fff;
background: purple;
}
input::-moz-selection
{
color: #fff;
background: purple;
}
```

Could any one tell me how to make that work with Chrome and other browsers? Created a fiddle with the entire code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sjeev/aRKLC/5/).

**Update**: I would like to clear myself that the question is about adding `::selection` for the text inside `<input>` and other form fields(explained in the question at first place). The question is not about `::selection` for normal text in browsers other than Firefox(works fine in Firefox). I never had problems adding `::selection` for non-form elements in any browser.

Comment: It works for me in Chrome 31.

Comment: @Pinal Here is a screenshot of the fiddle in my chrome- http://i.imgur.com/J1kNkrP.png

Comment: I'm using Chrome 31.0.1650.63(Mac OS X Mavericks). All is [fine](http://screencast.com/t/3v5XDbGH7kfe).

Comment: OP, if you're talking about selection inside `<input>`, then yes, it doesn't work in my Chrome (31, XP) either. The purple only applies to _the `<input>` element itself_, not its "shadow DOM".

Comment: @Pinal I have updated the question. Please check it for the screenshot of Firefox and chrome to understand how it actually appears and what I am expecting.

Comment: @Passerby Any solution to make it work in Chrome and Opera as it already works in Firefox?

Comment: @IamSJ Unfortunately I don't have any solution, and given that in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection) they said this is no longer a standard selector, I think you may be out of luck.

Comment: @Passerby Alright! I will continue enjoying it as it is now. Hope we get a alternative solution or a workaround for this in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they started supporting this selector.

`::selection` selector to give a color for the text inside `<input>` works fine on Chrome browser now. You can check the [same snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/sjeev/aRKLC/5/) on chrome to test.

[image]